# MobileFirst Analytics not working on other functions

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In ibm mobilefirst v7.0, I'm implementing the mfp analytics with angularjs.

"Log 1" is being showed in analytics console while "Log 2" is not.

Only the analytics that is called on my init function is being shown on the console, and on all the other functions, its not being shown on the console.

One weird encounter is the logs "MF analytics pushed to server successfully" is being called, so I could assume that its a success, but only "Log 1" is being shown and "Log 2" is not.

What could be the problem that "Log 2" is not being shown, or the logs on all other functions aside from init is not being shown on the console?

```
/** Initialization */
$scope.init = function() {
    var log = {
        "log" : "Log 1"
    }
    customMFAnalytics(log)
}

/** Called when the user press login */
$scope.login = function() {
    var log = {
        "log" : "Log 2"
    }
    customMFAnalytics(log)
}

$scope.init();

/** MFP Analytics */
function customMFAnalytics(event){
    WL.Analytics.log(event);
    WL.Analytics.send().then(function(state) {
        console.log("MF analytics pushed to server successfully");
    }).fail(function(errObj) {
        console.log("Error while pushing MF analytics to server");
    });;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if that second function is being called ? is an alert working from that function ?

Comment: Yes it si being called when i press login in my page, there's an html file for that. And the analytics is being called also, I can see the logs in my console, but in the analytics console, its not shown.

Comment: In general, WL.Analytics.log consumes json as WL.Analytics.log({"key" : 'value'});
Please use  JSON instead of string...

Comment: @krckumar, sorry I didn't notice that what I wrote as an example is not json. I edited it.. The data is correct since the 1st log was successful.